# How do I use reflection to determine the nested type (element type) of an array?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have an instance of System.Type, for which "IsArray" returns true.

How can I determine the "nested type" of the array type?

i.e.

```
Type GetArrayType(Type t)
{
    if(t.IsArray)
    {
        //  What to put here?
    }
    throw new Exception("Type is not an array");
}
Assert.That(GetArrayType(typeof(string[])), Iz.EqualTo(typeof(string));
Assert.That(GetArrayType(typeof(Foo[])), Iz.EqualTo(typeof(Foo));
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

```
t.GetElementType()
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype(VS.71).aspx).