# Get the type of an array object

Tags: c#, system.reflection, system.array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use reflection to determine the nested type of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840878/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-determine-the-nested-type-of-an-array)

I have a class A and trying to get the underlying type of an array in it.

```
Class A
{
   A1[] obja1;
   A2[] obja2;
   string x;
   int i;

}
```

How do I get the underlying object type of obja1 as A1 and obja2 as A2?Here is the part of the code I have:

```
    object AClass = myAssembly.CreateInstance("A");
    PropertyInfo[] pinfos = AClass.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach(PropertyInfo pinfo in pinfos)
    {
       if(pinfo.PropertyType.IsArray)
       {
             //here get the the underlying property type so that I can do something as follows
             var arr = myAssembly.CreateInstance(typeof(A1), 100);
//need to get if the array is array of A1 or A2 but do not want to hardcode

        }
    }
Thanks for the help..
```

Comment: By my reading, the question is asking how to create an instance of the array type, not the element type, so it is not necessarily a duplicate of the linked question.  To create an array, use `if (pinfo.PropertyType.IsArray) { var arr = Array.CreateInstance(pinfo.PropertyType.GetElementType, elementCount); ...` where elementCount is an integer variable holding the desired length of the array.

Comment: Thank you very much.. that was very dumb of me and totally forgot about GetElementType

Answer (score 2):

If I got question correctly. You may use [Get Element Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype.aspx) to get element type and compare it with required.

Or

Just use `typeof(A1[])` and `typeof(A2[])`