# How can I observe the value type of an array?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a method that checks the `Type` of an object to determine if it is complex:

```
private static bool IsComplexObject(Type type)
{
    if (IsNullable(type))
    {
        // nullable type, check if the nested type is simple
        return IsComplexObject(type.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
    }

    if (type.Equals(typeof(string)))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (type.Equals(typeof(decimal)))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (type.Equals(typeof(DataTable)))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (type.IsValueType)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (type.IsPrimitive)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (type.IsEnum)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The trouble is: when I have a `Type` of a simple type array, `Int32[]` for example, my method returns `true`.

I can prevent this from happening by adding this `if` statement into my method:

```
if (type.IsArray)
{
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that this `if` statement then prevents actual complex objects from being identified. For example, the following setup determines a custom class to not be complex:

```
public class TestClass
{ 
    public void TestComplexArray()
    {
        var result = IsComplexObject(typeof(MyComplexClass[]));

        // result == false
    }
}

public class MyComplexClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

So my question is: how can I check for the complexity of an array's value type to separate `Int32[]` from `MyComplexClass[]`?

Comment: What is your definition of a "Complex Type"? (I found only partical definitions on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_data_type | https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_data_type). Do you mean all classes? Well, any class can be given Indexers and thus act like an array (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/), so it is not really a simple exclusion. And indeed arrays are classes.

Comment: My definition of a complex class is outlined in my `IsComplexObject` method. The method works to identify my definition of complex object exactly how I need except for array types.

Comment: Have you tried [Type.GetElementType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype(v=vs.110).aspx)? It's crazy enough it just might work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840878/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-determine-the-nested-type-element-type-of-an-array should help you do what you want.

Comment: I do wonder what you want this for though... Particularly I wonder why all value types are considered not complex given that they can in fact be quite complicated and contain many many nested items. I mean, I am not 100% sure that you really want `public struct MyStruct{ public MyComplexClass Stuff {get; set;} }` to be counted as non-complex (though perhaps you do, I am not psychic).

Comment: @LukeTBrooks: As I said, any class can get a Indexer. The sample explicitly wraps a collection (array[t]) and implements an indexer. Would it also fit your definition of Array, so it should be excluded? Or would that be a complex type? You are going into a area of Programm where you have to take a stance on a lot of edge cases like these.

Comment: @Christopher: That isn't really an edge case. A class with an indexer is not an array. While they have similar syntax they are not the same thing.  `type.IsArray` makes this pretty clear and I think a safe stance would be to say that it is an array if that is true and if that is false then it is not an array... While I think a method like this *is* asking for trouble (see my previous comment) the definition of an array is not where this falls down.

Comment: Thanks guys! So I'm currently working on a small library that gathers the details of a C# Web API (controller names, methods on each controller, return types, parameters, etc) using Reflection and creates documentation for that API. So for this type information, I'm really just trying to determine if a given class would need a specific set of parameters in a JSON object to hit my API with a valid POST request; because I am currently working on a front-end that will create a custom form to test out any available method on an API.

Comment: @Chris: The Wikipedia definitions I found both consider "anything that has a indexer" as an Array. Considering Native C++ arrays do "index" by just adding [type width]x[index number] to the array pointer, the definition has to be pretty vague or half the langauges would not have one (the .NET array does the same under the hood. It just has a check if Index is viable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try retrieving the element type then calling `IsComplexObject` recursively, like so:

```
if (type.IsArray) return IsComplexObject(type.GetElementType());
```

This should return true for an array of "complex objects" (ones that do not meet the criteria specified in code). Just be warned, it'll also return true for an array of an array of complex objects, or an array of an array of an array. If that is a problem you can do make a change so that it'll only recurse once, like so:

```
private static bool IsComplexObject(Type type, bool recurse = true)
{
    if (type.IsArray) return 
    (
        recurse
        ? IsComplexObject(type.GetElementType(), false) 
        : false
    );
    //etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to check the array rank, and recur on the element type?

```
if (type.IsArray)
{
    if (type.GetArrayRank() != 1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    Type elementType = type.GetElementType();

    if (elementType.IsArray)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return IsComplexType(elementType);
}
```